# Convex hulls and convex combinations

Tags: convex-analysis, linear-programming, polytopes, convex-hulls

Why is it possible to represent **every point** contained in a convex hull as a convex combination of the points that generate the convex hull?

I am studying convex hulls for linear programming. I have not understood the above. I have understood that if I have only $2$ points (it's a line beetween them), but with more points I don't get the idea. Can you show me?

Comment: Commonly, the definition of "convex hull" is "the set of points that can be represented as a convex combination of the given points", in which case, your question is answered by definition. If this is not the definition you're using, what is?

Comment: You should add "with positive coefficients".

Comment: I dont understand why the set of points that can be represented as a convex combination of the given points is identically the set of points contained in the area of the convex hull.
For example. why the convex combinations of 3 points gives the area of a triangle ?

Comment: Should the sum of the coefficients equal 1?

Comment: "Convex combination" implies both "positive coefficients" and "adding up to 1".

Comment: You can make an even stronger statement with [Carathéodory's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_theorem_(convex_hull)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any convex combination of three or more points can be written as a "chain" of convex combinations of two points. For example, $\frac13 A + \frac13B + \frac13C$ can be expressed as $\frac13 A + \frac23(\frac12B + \frac12C)$: first we take the convex combination $\frac12B + \frac12C$, call the result $X$, and then take the convex combination $\frac13A + \frac23X$.

So if you understand why the convex combinations of two points form a line segment, you should understand why the convex combinations of three points form a triangle. If the points are $A$, $B$, and $C$, then:

- We can get every point $X$ on line segment $BC$ as a convex combination of $A$, $B$, and $C$.
- So any point on line segment $AX$ is a convex combination of $A$ and $X$: this, in turn is a convex combination of $A$, $B$, and $C$.
- As we move $X$ from $B$ to $C$, the segments $AX$ sweep out the entire area of $\triangle ABC$, as shown in the diagram below.

[image]